# React app taking too much time for loading on local system

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, localhost

I just started working on new reactjs app for learning purpose.

I installed app using this command: `npx create-react-app reactnotes`.

Then I am trying to start the app using this command: `yarn start`.

But in the browser it's been 2 minutes and the app is still loading but not opening on port http://localhost:3000/ default by React app. In the terminal
react-app-start only that is shown their and code is error-free.

[image]

Comment: What do you see in the terminal?

Comment: react-app-start only that is shown their and code is error free

Comment: is there anything in the browser console?

Comment: nope only react-app-start that is shown their and code is error-free

Comment: I mean in the browser devtools console which appears if you press `F12`

Comment: nope nothing is there even if we try that only localhost:3000 is showing there so we cannot able to see other things

Comment: do other browsers show the same blank page too?

Comment: same thing everywhere like that is frozen continuously loading

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and realized that it's happening while the network tab is open for the developer tool, so after I found the network throttling was enabled for "Fast 3G", just changed it to  "No Throttling", so the issue was solved
[image]